# Add items to Phalcon Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, model, many-to-many, phalcon

I have two models in many to may relationship - let's use lecturers and students as an example.

```
class Lecturer
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('studentId', 'Model\Entity\LecturerStudent', 'studentId', ['alias' => 'LecturerStudent']);
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'lecturerId',
            'Model\Entity\LecturerStudent',
            'lecturerId',
            'studentId',
            'Model\Entity\Student',
            'studentId',
            ['alias' => 'Students']
        );
    }
}

class LecturerStudent
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('studentId', 'Model\Entity\Student', 'studentId', ['alias' => 'Student']);
        $this->belongsTo('lecturerId', 'Model\Entity\Lecturer', 'lecturerId', ['alias' => 'Lecturer']);
    }
}

class Student
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('lecturerId', 'Model\Entity\LecturerStudent', 'lecturerId', ['alias' => 'LecturerStudent']);
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to add students to lecturers all I need to do is:

```
$lecturerA = new Lecturer();
$studentA = new Student();
$studentB = new Student();
$lecturerA->Students = [$studentA, $studentB];
$lecturerA->save();
```

This all works as I'd expect.

The problem arises in my application when I'm importing a number of records in one transaction and I need to add a second array to the relationship.

So in the example:

```
$lecturerA = new Lecturer();
$studentA = new Student();
$studentB = new Student();
$lecturerA->Students = [$studentA, $studentB];

... other code doing other things ...

$studentC = new Student();
$studentD = new Student();
$lecturerA->Students = [$studentC, $studentD];

... more code ...

$lecturerA->save();
```

In this case, only the item(s) added in the second assignment to `Students` are saved. The item(s) from the first assignment are lost. So in my example only `studentC` and `studentD` will be written to the database.

Is there a correct way to do this - to add to a previous many-to-many array - in Phalcon? I have an alternative (messier) way to do this within the class that's performing the import, but if there's a correct way I'd much prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store students objects to temporary array, because second assignment will overwrite `$lectureA->Students`.

```
$lecturerA = new Lecturer();
$studentA = new Student();
$studentB = new Student();
$tmpStudents = [$studentA, $studentB];

... other code doing other things ...

$studentC = new Student();
$studentD = new Student();
$tmpStudents = $tmpStudents + [$studentC, $studentD];
$lecturerA->Students = $tmpStudents;

... more code ...

$lecturerA->save();
```

or you can call `$lecturerA->save()` method after you set students relationship.But off course this will cause higher network traffic because each time you call `save()`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query will have to be made to RDBMS.

```
$lecturerA = new Lecturer();
$studentA = new Student();
$studentB = new Student();
$lecturerA->Students = [$studentA, $studentB];
$lecturerA->save();

... other code doing other things ...

$studentC = new Student();
$studentD = new Student();
$lecturerA->Students = [$studentC, $studentD];

... more code ...

$lecturerA->save();
```